# Module `react-native-screens` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: javascript, npm, react-native, node-modules

I am having an error when try to run the project.

bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-screens` from `H:\T16\Booster\node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\views\StackView\StackViewCard.js`: Module `react-native-screens` does not exist in the Haste module map

here is the screenshot of the error in node
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvn8c.png)

I have already installed these packages as people suggested

"react-native-screens"

"react-native-reanimated"

"react-native-gesture-handler"

my react native version is 59.5

- Tried removing node_module multiple time,
- tried resetting cache,
- Reset Metro Bundler cache,
- migrated to androidx properly.

But still not solved yet. Here I am giving the package.json file

```html
{
  "name": "Booster",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^0.6.14",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.4",
    "firebase": "^7.6.0",
    "grpc": "^1.20.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.4",
    "react-native-pie": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-screen": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.10.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-native-screens this is the package. But in your package.json file it is only react-native-screen. please change this.